# Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14) withEndAction

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I added animate method to `OnItemClickListener()` on list view but I got this error:

```
Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14): android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator#withEndAction
```

I know that the withEndAction method was added in API Level 16, and older devices do not have it but I want use this animate or like this in my API.
How can i do that?

```
listViewHome.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  final View view1 = view;
  final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable(){
       @Override
         public void run() {
             contacts.remove(item);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             view1.setAlpha(1);
          }
         });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a listener with an `AnimatorListenerAdapter`. For Example... of course you should have a different behavior for `SDK <16` and `>=16`

```
.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
   @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
         //code here
     }
   });
```